# Installing Teradata Database

Tags: teradata

I was reading about data warehousing and came to know about Teradata. But I didn't found any links on teradata website to download teradata database. Can I install teradata database on my windows or linux machine. Or its like a combination of software and hardware together to be purchased from Teradata

Answer (score 5):

There's no standalone demo install of Teradata available. Go to Teradata's Developer Exchange instead and download a VMWare image of a fully featured TD system with up to 40 GB of available space.

http://downloads.teradata.com/download/database/teradata-express/vmware

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth on the download page that you have mentioned for first download it shows 4GB and second download it shows 40 GB. Which one to download and what all the things does teradata express contains

Comment: @MahtabAlam: All newer VMs are 40GB, there's only an old TD14 version with 4GB. The images contain a full TD running on Suse Enterprise Linux including the Linux client. There are some links on that page with further info. A Windows client you can download here: http://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-tools-and-utilities-windows-installation-package

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks a lot for provided links, as  a part of my master's degree I  need to make a study of a physical design in TD. Is that image suitable?

Comment: @Rocketq: Of course, it's the exactly the same database software you get on a real TD system, just limited to two AMPs with 40 GB instead of hundreds or thousands of AMPs with multi-TB or multi-PB disc space.

Comment: Is there any docker image available?

Comment: @uday: No, no docker, only VMWare VMs